# -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Users\Public\wpilib\2022\jdk"" terminated with exit code: 1

Tags: java, robotics

Working on a script for a RoboRIO in relation to the FRC. I'm unable to deploy the code. I'm not sure what I can do in order to proceed in deploying the code.

I attempted going into the properties json file and entering the team number manually into all the files. (I was expecting this to fix the issue, but unfortunately did not)

I also attempted to resolve the issue by reformatting the RoboRIO (This did not fix the issue either)

I can make a communication connection, and joystick connections, just no success with the Robot Code.

Comment: As someone with FRC experience, you’d have more luck posting on Chief Delphi. They’ll have more Roborio specific knowledge.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.